# Running total column in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, sum

I've looked at a lot of examples here but I still can't seem to get this to work.

I have a database in `SQLite`. A `Date`, `PL`, and `Total_PL` column...

I want to sum the PL column with a running total on each row of the Total_PL column...

What's the best way to do this? I would think a Trigger, but I've tried that and it just populates every single row with the same value...

Please help and thanks...

Comment: Why can't you calculate running totals on the fly when you need them, say for reporting or displaying on a UI?

Answer (score 1):

did you try?

```
SELECT PL, SUM(Total_PL) as RunningTotal
FROM tableName
GROUP BY PL
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?  The OP wants to sum `PL`, and update `Total_PL` with the running total.